# Сэмулировать POST на другой сайт

Tags: php, post

При сабмите формы, данные отправляются по указанному урлу методом post.

Как тоже самое сделать автоматически?
Т.е. например я открываю site1.ru/page.php
На этой странице формируются данные.
И происходит переход на site2.com/page/ , который принимает данные.

С помощью curl или file_get_contents можно же только отправить данные и получить выданный контент? но нужно именно перейти на второй урл.

**UPD:**  для вообще чего это нужно.
Во первых в принципе хочу узнать возможно ли это.

А конкретно сейчас задача такая:

на site1 есть кнопка "оплатить"

site2 - это https://money.yandex.ru/quickpay/confirm.xml - принимает только POST.

Хочу сделать чтобы после нажатия на кнопку оплаты, подключалась отдельная страница (site1.ru/page.php) где бы формировался специальный параметр, и пользователь вместе post данными отправляется на site2.com/page/

Comment: Так ты распарси форму и на `site2.com/page/` c помощью `Curl` сразу `POST'ом` оставляй необходимые данные. Минуя первую страницу

Comment: @Vladimir _но нужно именно перейти на второй урл_ - имеется ввиду, перенаправить браузер? Если да, то `header('Location: http://site.ru');`

Comment: Эдуард, header('Location: http://site.ru') - и сюда как то можно вписать POST данные?

Comment: Erm, так потом на site2.com/page/ идет дальнейшая работа с данными

Comment: @Vladimir нет, функция header() может отправлять только методом GET. Для передачи данных методом POST нужно использовать CURL, а если после отправки запроса надо перенаправить браузер на сайт.ру, то использовать header()

Comment: @Эдуард, 
я не могу сначала отправить данные на Site2 а потом отдельно от данных перейти туда. в этом смысла нет.

Comment: @Vladimir а почему именно пост данные? В header() же можно дописать гет параметры.

Comment: @Vladimir не мешало бы в вашем первом посту дописать код того, что вы хотите сделать - так было бы понятнее ваша задача для всех остальных участников. Можете отредактировать ваш первый пост.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69248/discussion-between--and-vladimir).

Comment: @Эдуард обновил пост

Answer (score 0):

Получается что ответ на вопрос - это невозможно.

вот подобная задача рассматривалась тут: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5576619/php-redirect-with-post-data

Comment: @IDrakonl, ответ на вопрос - такое сделать невозможно. 
 Свою задачу я уже обрисовал в обновлении вопроса (UPD) - это просто пояснение для чего мне это нужно, - и это и разбирается по той ссылке .. там много чего. так сразу однозначно и не написать..

Comment: Признаю, был не прав